# Angular documentation about controller this

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, controller, angularjs-scope

I recently read in angular documentation (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/docs/guide/providers) this:

```
myApp.controller('DemoController', ['clientId', function DemoController(clientId) {
  this.clientId = clientId;
}]);
```

associated to:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <body ng-controller="DemoController as demo">
    Client ID: {{demo.clientId}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Then I was surprised because `this` was used instead of an injected `$scope` service.

I tried to reproduce with success, then I'm wondering if someone could explain one use-case where using controller instance is preferable to injected `$scope`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [John Papa's style guide about `controllerAs`](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controlleras-view-syntax):

> ... the controllerAs syntax is closer to that of a JavaScript constructor than the classic $scope syntax
>
> It promotes the use of binding to a "dotted" object in the View (e.g. customer.name instead of name), which is more contextual, easier to read, and avoids any reference issues that may occur without "dotting".
>
> Helps avoid using $parent calls in Views with nested controllers.

The biggest benefit I've found in my general day-to-day use of this is the fact that it provides a concept of namespacing in controllers instead of just having this feeling of "free variables" roaming around your markup.

That's especially important if you have nested controllers, because it provides a way to namespace variables (even ones with the same name), but ensure they are in the context of the correct controller.

Comment: For namespacing variables on scope I'm using object hierarchy: `$scope.mynamespace = {var1: 5, var2: 6};` for example.

Comment: @G.Ghez you're doing exactly what `controllerAs` does under the hood :)

Comment: @G.Ghez, if you look at the Angular source code, you'll see that `controllerAs` is just a convenient way of doing `$scope.<someNameSpace>`

Comment: It also provides dot notation out of the box so variables maintain reference

Comment: I may agree, but then, could we just stop using `$scope` in favor of controller instance? I'm wondering about `$scope.$watch`, `.$on`...

Comment: @G.Ghez, yes if you're going to still be using `$scope` for specific `$scope` methods like you mentioned, then you'll still have to inject `$scope` and use it. Angular 2 does away with that completely as far as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Why it's better to use `controller as` is well described in [this guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controllers).

> Why?: Controllers are constructed, "newed" up, and provide a single
>   new instance, and the controllerAs syntax is closer to that of a
>   JavaScript constructor than the classic $scope syntax.
>
> Why?: It promotes the use of binding to a "dotted" object in the View
>   (e.g. customer.name instead of name), which is more contextual, easier
>   to read, and avoids any reference issues that may occur without
>   "dotting".
>
> Why?: Helps avoid using $parent calls in Views with nested
>   controllers.

It's best however to use a specialized variable to access controller instance:

```
myApp.controller('DemoController', ['clientId', '$scope', function DemoController(clientId, $scope) {
  var self = this;
  self.clientId = clientId;

  //to watch the vars
  $scope.$watch('self.clientId', function(new, old) {});
}]);
```

Comment: where `$scope` here is coming from? ;)

Comment: Also, I think, watcher should be applied to `clientId` only, not `self.clientId`

Comment: @G.Ghez Nope, the `self.clientId` is correct. Please check this section: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controlleras-with-vm

Comment: Then I have another concern explained in another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483905/angularjs-scope-not-watching-changes-from-view

Comment: @G.Ghez Yep, answered. The `self` should be used as the alias of the controller in the view: ng-controller="controller as self".

Comment: I understand this build, but I'm a little bit disturbed by hard link (named alias) it creates between controller and view.