# AngularJS $scope not watching changes from View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, controller, watch

I have this small sample in which I hoped to see log messages in browser console indicating $scope watcher is working well, but it's unfortunately not the case.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demo">

<head>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('demo', ['ng']);
    app.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope) {
        var self = this;

        self.searchText = '';
        $scope.$watch('self.searchText', function(n, p) {
            console.log('searchText changed from', n, 'to', p);
        });

    });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="demoCtrl as ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.searchText" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the alias `ctrl` (not `self`) in `$scope.$watch(...)`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demo">

<head>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('demo', ['ng']);
    app.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope) {
        var self = this;

        self.searchText = '';
        $scope.$watch('ctrl.searchText', function(n, p) {
            console.log('searchText changed from', n, 'to', p);
        });

    });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="demoCtrl as ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.searchText" />
</body>

</html>
```

When `ng-controller="demoCtrl as ctrl"` is used, Angular creates a link to the controller context object `this` into the scope: `$scope.ctrl`.

Comment: Now I understand, so documentation here may be incomplete when talking about watching local variable `vm`: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controlleras-with-vm

Comment: @G.Ghez Agreed, it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Btw, as I said in a previous question (but in order to maintain feed knowledge here too), Both view and controller have an agreement on a variable name here which create a hard link between them. I'm not so fan of that...

Comment: @G.Ghez It's more a personal preference. I use the `controller as` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `$watch` to:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return self.searchText;
  }, function(n, p) {
    console.log('searchText changed from', n, 'to', p);
  });
```

Comment: if you observe variable assigned to `$scope` you can use string notation, but if it is variable not assign to `$scope` you have to use function.

Comment: I understand.  But put it *in your answer*.  that will make it a much better answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

In [form you used](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) `$scope.$watch` watching expression should be part of scope or root scope.
So you should change your code like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demo">

<head>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('demo', ['ng']);
    app.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope) {
        var self = this;

        $scope.searchText = '';
        $scope.$watch('searchText', function(n, p) {
            console.log('searchText changed from', n, 'to', p);
        });

    });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="demoCtrl as ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" />
</body>

</html>
```

or use another form and change you code like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('demo', ['ng']);
    app.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope) {
        var self = this;

        self.searchText = '';
        $scope.$watch(function() { return self.searchText; }, function(n, p) {
            console.log('searchText changed from', n, 'to', p);
        });

    });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="demoCtrl as ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.searchText" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple -

Angular watches the expression on the scope variable and not on the controller instance.

To make the code work you need to do modify the controller code as following

```
var self = this;

self.searchText = '';
$scope.self = this;
$scope.$watch('self.searchText', function(n, p) {
console.log('searchText changed from', n, 'to', p);
});
```

Comment: "controller as" build allows to automatically attach controller instance to scope. See: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controlleras-with-vm